# Confused about how to connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to develop a a website with React, MySQL, and Node.js. I am a beginner. I have done the front end part and need to create the data models and the apis to interact with database. I am confused about how to go about doing this. If I connect to a MySQL server on my local machine, how can I launch the website on AWS?

Comment: The usual approach is to make the database configuration an external file (e.g. JSON) that you can customize when you deploy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create & run your application on your local machine with local MYSQL setups. After completing & running the application you can do the necessary configurations on AWS to run on their own MYSQL instance when deploying the application. Here is a sample post that you can refer it to get some idea... [DEPLOY A REACT + NODE APP TO PRODUCTION ON AWS](https://dev.to/asim_ansari7/deploy-a-react-node-app-to-production-on-aws-2gdf)